# How solve this nonlinear trigonometric differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, special-functions, trigonometric-integrals, nonlinear-analysis

sHello to everyone, i would like a suggestion on how solve this nonlinear differential equations:

$$y''+ a\ x\cos y=0 $$

where $a \in \mathbb{R}\ and \ \ y=y(x) $

I am aware that if a solution can be found it will be a series solution,
for example, proceeding with the power series could lead to some result?

Or what replacement do I need to bring it back to the first order?

Thank you in advance for any idea or proposed solution.

P.S. I have not yet been able to find out if this differential equation has already been resolved in literature.

Comment: i think you will Need a numerical method

Comment: Unfortunately I need a non-numeric solution.
As I already wrote, it would be very good to have a series solution, and I believe that in series of powers can be found, but I have not managed to retrieve it after several attempts

Comment: A series solution with $\cos y$ is a mess!
$$\cos y(x)=\frac{1}{6} x^3 \left(-y^{(3)}(0) \sin (y(0))+y'(0)^3 \sin (y(0))-3 y'(0) y''(0) \cos (y(0))\right)+x^2 \left(-\frac{1}{2} y''(0) \sin (y(0))-\frac{1}{2} y'(0)^2 \cos (y(0))\right)-x y'(0) \sin (y(0))+\cos (y(0))+O(x^4)$$
I have only written the first $4$ terms...

Comment: unfortunately, but perhaps it is the only way

Comment: How many terms of $y$ do you want?

Comment: I have to be quite precise, so I believe many

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compute a power series up to any desired order, you can use the tools of Taylor series arithmetic that are a part of the Automatic/Algorithmic Differentiation theory. As differentiation of a power series contains an index shift, new coefficients result on the left side while evaluating or updating the evaluation on the right side.

To simplify the Taylor series arithmetic introduce $u=\cos y$, $v=\sin y$. Then
\begin{align}
u'&=-vy'\\
v'&=~~~uy'\\
y''&=-axu.
\end{align}
This is now a problem where the multiplication of Taylor series is the most complicated operation which allows to establish the equations for the coefficients of these 3 series
$$y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty y_kx^k, ~~~u=\sum_{n=0}^\infty u_kx^k,~~~  v=\sum_{n=0}^\infty v_kx^k.
$$
These can then be computed by successively inserting the already computed coefficients,

\begin{align}
y_0&=y(0)&  u_0&=\cos(y_0),&  v_0&=\sin(y_0),\\
y_1&=y'(0)&  u_1&=-v_0y_1,&    v_1&=u_0y_1,\\
2y_2&=0,&  2u_2&=-v_0(2y_2)-v_1y_1,&  2v_2&=u_0(2y_2)+u_1y_1,\\
6y_3&=-au_0,&    3u_3&=-\sum_{k=1}^3v_{3-k}(ky_k),&    3v_3&=\sum_{k=1}^3u_{3-k}(ky_k),\\
&\vdots\\
n(n-1)y_n&=-au_{n-3},&nu_n&=-\sum_{k=1}^nv_{n-k}(ky_k),&    nv_n&=\sum_{k=1}^nu_{n-k}(ky_k),\\
\end{align}

For further information on the automatic creation of such algorithms, see

- **FADBAD++** by Stauning and Bendtsen (project active 1996-2003), the third example in the [crash-course](http://www.imm.dtu.dk/%7Ekajm/FADBAD/#CrashCourse) section of their description site,
- [**VNODE**](http://www.cas.mcmaster.ca/%7Enedialk/Software/VNODE/VNODE.shtml), used for examples in papers by [N. Nedialkov](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/NA/reports.html#stepsize.99a) (2001)
- [**TSM** - ODE playground](https://github.com/m4r35n357/ODE-Playground/blob/master/README.md) by user m4r35n357 (active 2018-), Taylor series manipulation with a focus on ODE

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Let $y=iu$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=i\dfrac{du}{dx}$

$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=i\dfrac{d^2u}{dx^2}$

$\therefore i\dfrac{d^2u}{dx^2}+ax\cos iu=0$

$\dfrac{d^2u}{dx^2}-iax\cosh u=0$

$\dfrac{d^2u}{dx^2}-\dfrac{iaxe^u}{2}-\dfrac{iaxe^{-u}}{2}=0$

Let $v=e^u$ ,

Then $u=\ln v$

$\dfrac{du}{dx}=\dfrac{1}{v}\dfrac{dv}{dx}$

$\dfrac{d^2u}{dx^2}=\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{1}{v}\dfrac{dv}{dx}\right)=\dfrac{1}{v}\dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2}-\dfrac{1}{v^2}\left(\dfrac{dv}{dx}\right)^2$

$\therefore\dfrac{1}{v}\dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2}-\dfrac{1}{v^2}\left(\dfrac{dv}{dx}\right)^2-\dfrac{iaxv}{2}-\dfrac{iax}{2v}=0$

$2v\dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2}-2\left(\dfrac{dv}{dx}\right)^2-iaxv^3-iaxv=0$