# Power Series Solution with Trigonometry

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Suppose we want to find a power series solution to this common physics-based ODE Initial Value Problem:
Just need the first 5 or so terms, not the full general solution.
$$-x'' = -kx' -sinx$$
$$x(0)=0 \; \text{and} \; x'(0)=1$$

My Process:

Ansatz: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nt^n$$ 
Firstly, observe that based on our initial values, this tells us that $a_0=0$ and $a_1=1$.

Plugging this into our ODE, we have:
$$\implies -\frac{d^2}{dt^2}  \left[ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nt^n \right] = -k\frac{d}{dt} \left[ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nt^n \right] -\sin \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nt^n \right)$$

$$\implies -\left[\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{n-2}(n)(n-1)t^{n-2} \right] = -k \left[ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n-1}(n)t^{n-1} \right] -sin \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nt^n \right) $$

$$\implies 0= \left[\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{n-2}(n)(n-1)t^{n-2} \right] -k \left[ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n-1}(n)t^{n-1} \right] - \left[ \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^m}{(2m+1)} \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n t^n \right)^{2m+1} \; \right] $$

This is clearly too messy to work with, so I had the idea of making my ansatz just power 7 let's say if I wanted my solution to be up to power 5. However, I assume the expansion of this would also be computationally too intensive. What am I missing here? Is there an easier Ansatz incorporating matrices to make this computationally doable???

Comment: Are all the signs in the original equation correct? For a pendulum with friction I would expect $x''+kx'+\sin x=0$.

Comment: Could you work with [this approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2499684/115115) for a similar question, a power series for $y''(x)+ax\cos(y(x))=0$.